# how to look at txt file at 10-20-30-40-50-60-70-80-90 percent marks?

Tags: command-line-interface

I have a large txt file, using CLI I can take a look at the beginning of the file using"

```
head file.txt
```

at the end:

```
tail file.txt
```

How do I take a look at the 10 percent of the file, 20 percent of the file, etc?

Comment: Voting to move to www.superuser.com, but @text, you might want to add some more details. At least mention what OS you're working with.

Answer (score 4):

Note that

- in the GNU less pager you can simply type <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and go there
- vim has the same feature in normal mode (not in Vi)

  {count}%    Go to {count} percentage in the file, on the first
          non-blank in the line |linewise|.  To compute the new
          line number this formula is used:
              ({count} * number-of-lines + 99) / 100
          See also 'startofline' option.  {not in Vi}

This, for *my* purposes, removes all need for such a thing

Comment: @RaffiM Yesterday, I learned that **[they can even be nested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10508098/85371)** (see under 'For fun: Ascii art')

Answer (score 2):

You can create an alias for "mid" to select a range of lines.

As for percentages, you'll probably need a script instead of a one liner so that you determine how many lines are in the file and then what line 10% starts at

```
alias mid 'tail -n +\!:1 \!:3* | head -n \!:2'
```

See: http://www.fastechws.com/tricks/unix/head_tail_mid_files.php