# How do I visual select a calculation backwards?

Tags: regex, search, vim, select

I would like to visual select backwards a calculation p.e.

```
200 + 3 This is my text -300 +2 + (9*3)
                        |-------------|*

This is text 0,25 + 2.000 + sqrt(15/1.5)
             |-------------------------|*
```

The reason is that I will use it in insert mode.
After writing a calculation I want to select the calculation (using a map) and put the results of the calculation in the text.

What the regex must do is:
- select from the cursor (see `*` in above example) backwards to the start of the calculation
(including `\/-+*:.,^`).
- the calculation can start only with log/sqrt/abs/round/ceil/floor/sin/cos/tan or with  a positive or negative number
- the calculation can also start at the beginning of the line but it never goes back to 
a previous line

I tried in all ways but could not find the correct regex.
I noted that backward searching is different then forward searching.

Can someone help me?

**Edit**
Forgot to mention that it must **include** also the '=' if there is one and if the '=' is before the cursor or if there is only space between the cursor and '='.
It must not include other '=' signs.

```
200 + 3 = 203 -300 +2 + (9*3) =
          |-------------------|<SPACES>*

200 + 3 = 203 -300 +2 + (9*3)
          |-----------------|<SPACES>*
```

`*` = where the cursor is

Comment: why do you want to do it 'backwards' ? BTW: in your first example there is none of the keywords you mentioned - do you need to revise the rules ?

Comment: Hello Joanna, you're right but backwards was not in the keywords list. I want to do it backwards because when I'm in insert mode I want to capture the calculation I've just written, calculate the results and put the results in the text. Hope I made myself clear. Thank you for commenting.

Comment: what i meant is that this example `200 + 3 This is my text -300 +2 + (9*3)` doesn't contain any of the keywords `log/sqrt/abs/round/ceil/floor/sin/cos/tan`.

Comment: Yes it is only an example of one of the calculations but I also use the log, sqrt and these others in my calculations. Another calculation can be `sqrt(2)` that's why I mentioned the sqrt.

Comment: I'm not any of the downvoters, maybe the task in the question does not seem like a good way to achieve what you want to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex that comes close in pure vim is

```
\v\c\s*\zs(\s{-}(((sqrt|log|sin|cos|tan|exp)?\(.{-}\))|(-?[0-9,.]+(e-?[0-9]+)?)|([-+*/%^]+)))+(\s*\=?)?\s*
```

There are limitations: subexpressions (including function arguments) aren't parsed. You'd need to use a proper grammar parser to do that, and I don't recommend doing that in pure vim<sup>1</sup>

### Operator Mapping

To enable using this a bit like text-objects, use something like this in your $MYVIMRC:

```
func! DetectExpr(flag)
    let regex = '\v\c\s*\zs(\s{-}(((sqrt|log|sin|cos|tan|exp)?\(.{-}\))|(-?[0-9,.]+(e-?[0-9]+)?)|([-+*/%^]+)))+(\s*\=?)?\s*' 
    return searchpos(regex, a:flag . 'ncW', line('.'))
endf

func! PositionLessThanEqual(a, b)
    "echo 'a: ' . string(a:a)
    "echo 'b: ' . string(a:b)
    if (a:a[0] == a:b[0])
        return (a:a[1] <= a:b[1]) ? 1 : 0
    else
        return (a:a[0] <= a:b[0]) ? 1 : 0
    endif
endf

func! SelectExpr(mustthrow)
    let cpos  = getpos(".")
    let cpos  = [cpos[1], cpos[2]] " use only [lnum,col] elements
    let begin = DetectExpr('b')
    if ( ((begin[0] == 0) && (begin[1] == 0))
      \ || !PositionLessThanEqual(begin, cpos) )
        if (a:mustthrow)
            throw "Cursor not inside a valid expression"
        else
            "echoerr "not satisfied: " . string(begin) . " < " . string(cpos)
        endif
        return 0
    endif
    "echo "satisfied: " . string(begin) . " < " . string(cpos)

    call setpos('.', [0, begin[0], begin[1], 0])
    let end = DetectExpr('e')
    if ( ((end[0] == 0) || (end[1] == 0))
      \ || !PositionLessThanEqual(cpos,  end) )
        call setpos('.', [0, cpos[0], cpos[1], 0])
        if (a:mustthrow)
            throw "Cursor not inside a valid expression"
        else
            "echoerr "not satisfied: " . string(begin) . " < " . string(cpos) . " < " . string(end) 
        endif
        return 0
    endif
    "echo "satisfied: " . string(begin) . " < " . string(cpos) . " < " . string(end) 

    norm! v
    call setpos('.', [0, end[0],   end[1],   0])
    return 1
endf

silent! unmap X
silent! unmap <M-.>

xnoremap <silent>X :<C-u>call SelectExpr(0)<CR>
onoremap <silent>X :<C-u>call SelectExpr(0)<CR>
```

Now you can operator on the nearest expression around (or after) the cursor position:

- <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>   - [v]isually select e[X]pression
- <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>   - [d]elete current e[X]pression
- <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>   - [y]ank current e[X]pression
- `"a`<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>   - id. to register `a`

As a trick, use the following to arrive at the exact ascii art from the OP (using *virtualedit* for the purpose of the demo):

### Insert mode mapping

In response to the chat:

```
" if you want trailing spaces/equal sign to be eaten:
imap <M-.> <C-o>:let @e=""<CR><C-o>"edX<C-r>=substitute(@e, '^\v(.{-})(\s*\=?)?\s*$', '\=string(eval(submatch(1)))', '')<CR>

" but I'm assuming you wanted them preserved:
imap <M-.> <C-o>:let @e=""<CR><C-o>"edX<C-r>=substitute(@e, '^\v(.{-})(\s*\=?\s*)?$', '\=string(eval(submatch(1))) . submatch(2)', '')<CR>
```

allows you to hit <kbd>Alt-.</kbd> during insert mode and the current expression gets replaced with it's evaluation. The cursor ends up at the end of the result in insert mode.

```
200 + 3 This is my text -300 +2 + (9*3)

This is text 0.25 + 2.000 + sqrt(15/1.5)
```

Tested by pressing <kbd>Alt-.</kbd> in insert 3 times:

```
203 This is my text -271

This is text 5.412278
```

### For Fun: ascii art

#### <kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>X</kbd></kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd></kbd><kbd><kbd>`</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>j</kbd></kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>X</kbd></kbd><kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>-</kbd></kbd><kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>|</kbd></kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

To easily test it yourself:

```
:let @q="vXoyo\x1b`<jPvXr-r|e.a*\x1b"
:set virtualedit=all
```

Now you can <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> anywhere and it will ascii-decorate the nearest expression :)

```
200 + 3 = 203 -300 +2 + (9*3) =
|-------|*
          |-------------------|*

200 + 3 = 203 -300 +2 + (9*3)
          |-----------------|*
|-------|*

This is text 0,25 + 2.000 + sqrt(15/1.5)
             |-------------------------|*
```

---

<sup>1</sup> consider using Vim's python integration to do such parsing

Comment: Wow what a great script. Thank you very much!!! I added the `=` sign to the selection (hope I did it right). ( I check it afterwards and put the answer after the `=` sign if there is one). I added also a `+` after the exponential. This is my new one `call search('\v\c((((sqrt|log|.?sin|.?cos|.?tan|abs|round|ceil|floor|len|ln|exp)?\(.{-}\))|(-?[0-9,.]+(e[-+]?[0-9]+)?)|([-+*/%^]+))\s*\=?\s*)+', a:flag . 'csW')`  Sometimes I use also `!=` `==` `<` `>` in calculations p.e. `5/7 > 6/9` answer = [01]. Where would you place this in the function Sehe?

Comment: Added a macro that demoes using the text-object to reproduce the **ascii art** from the OP

Comment: I noted that it selects also the `\n` character if I'm at the end of a line. `eval("my-visual-selection")` gives an error because of the EOL character in the selection.

Comment: This is the error: `-300 +2 + (9*3)^@` Error: E488: Trailing characters. --> `^@` means EOL isn't it?

Comment: Ermm... `\s` doesn't match EOL. Also, just filter it out? That will be more maintainable than adapting the regex. Look at `substitute`, `strpart`. Are you actually using vim's `eval` function here?

Comment: @remio That looks like the NUL char to me. Check your source text (`:se list!` and `8g8` might help; `%!xxd` if all else fails)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11046/discussion-between-sehe-and-remio)

Comment: `:imap <M-.> <C-o>"edX<C-r>=eval(@e)` works fine for me, even keeps you in insert mode

Answer (score 1):

This seems quite a complicated task after all to achieve with regex, so if you can avoid it in any way, try to do so.

I've created a regex that works for a few examples - give it a try and see if it does the trick:

```
^(?:[A-Za-z]|\s)+((?:[^A-Za-z]+)?(?:log|sqrt|abs|round|ceil|floor|sin|cos|tan)[^A-Za-z]+)(?:[A-Za-z]|\s)*$
```

The part that you are interested in should be in the first matching group.

Let me know if you need an explanation.

EDIT:

`^` - match the beginning of a line

`(?:[A-Za-z]|\s)+` - match everything that's a letter or a space once or more

match and capture the following 3:
`((?:[^A-Za-z]+)?` - match everything that's NOT a letter (i.e. in your case numbers or operators)

`(?:log|sqrt|abs|round|ceil|floor|sin|cos|tan)` - match one of your keywords

`[^A-Za-z]+)` - match everything that's NOT a letter (i.e. in your case numbers or operators)

`(?:[A-Za-z]|\s)*` - match everything that's a letter or a space zero or more times

`$` - match the end of the line

Comment: tnx for your answer. Did you use perl regex?

Comment: @remio - it should be the perl flavour yes, there's nothing very advanced in the regex anyway, so it should work in most languages

Comment: @remio - I'm not familiar with vim, but seems that at least the capturing groups have to be escaped, so `\(` rather than `(`, same for the closing brackets - you can try removing the `?:` bit as well as it might not be supported - I don't have time to go through this unfortunately but there seems to be a good reference here  http://vimregex.com/#backreferences . Once all the required special chars are escaped it should work