# How do I use a map in combination with search matches?

Tags: search, vim, maps, match

How do I use a map on every match found after a search?

I have created various functions which I invoke using a map.
I would like to use the maps on every search matches found.

If I search for dates in my text, how would I apply a i/v/nmap on every search-match found?

something like this?

```
%s/search-pattern/=\normal mode map/g
%s/search-pattern/=\insert mode map/g
```

Is it possible also to combine maps?

Hope I made myself clear.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do? This is a classic case of the **[XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)**. Don't ask how you can do a detail, ask how you can achieve a goal. Chances are that the detail isn't relevant at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim is quite powerful, and I suspect insert mode/normal mode maps are not the most convenient approach here.

Some idioms that may get you started:

> <sub>**Edit:** I've built on your earlier question (
> [How do I visual select a calculation backwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494321/how-do-i-visual-select-a-calculation-backwar/10508098#10508098)
> ) and provided a demo, explained [in
> chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3687661#3687661)</sub>

### 1. Record a macro:

```
qqniMyText<Esc>q
```

This will insert 'MyText' at each match position. Now, repeat a hundred times: 100@q
(consider setting `:se nowrapscan` to avoid restarting from the top).

### 2. Use `:global`

```
:g/somepattern/norm! Aappended<Esc>
```

will append the text 'appended' to each line containing the search pattern

### 3. Use smart substitutions:

You can do some 'static' edit actions using replacement patterns:

```
:%s/\v(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d{4})/\3\2\1/g
```

To transform dd-mm-yyyy into yyyymmdd date stamps.

To do a dynamically evaluated substitution (using vimscript with `\=` in the replacement expression) you can do virtually anything (including, sending mail or printing a document, if you would really want to):

```
:%s/\v<DB_\w+>/\=substitute(submatch(0), '\v_?([^_])([^_]*)', '\U\1\L\2', 'g')/g
```

To transform 'database style' names like

```
var DB_USER_ID = f();
var DB_USER_FIRST_NAME = f();
var DB_USER_LAST_NAME = f();
var DB_USER_HOME_ADDRESS = f();
```

into 'camel case style names' like:

```
var DbUserId = f();
var DbUserFirstName = f();
var DbUserLastName = f();
var DbUserHomeAddress = f();
```

---

### Live demo with expression evaluations

**Edit** In response to the comment/chat: You can use the approach #1 for this quite easily:

```
/\v\c\s*\zs(\s{-}(((sqrt|log|sin|cos|tan|exp)?\(.{-}\))|(-?[0-9,.]+(e-?[0-9]+)?)|([-+*/%^]+)))+(\s*\=?)?\s*
qqa<M-.><Esc>nq
```

Now you can repeat for all of the document:

```
:set nowrapscan
100@q
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Sehe, take p.e. your beautiful solution to calculate calculations written in the text. As you know, I use a function for it with an imap <M-,>. `%s/"search-for-calculations"/\=exe "normal a\<M-,>"/gc` doesnt work. In the past I had more functions (with mapping) I wished to apply to search-matches but never found a solution.

Comment: @remio: **[answering in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3687653#3687653)**

Answer (score 3):

If there's only one match in every line, you could use `:global` instead of `:s`:

```
:%g/search-pattern/normal nrX
```

The `:[range]normal` positions the cursor at the beginning of the line, therefore the `n` to go to the first match before the mapping (I use `rX` as an example). You *could* write a custom command that would handle all matches in a line, but I would solve your use case with a recursive macro instead:

First, perform the search: `/search-pattern`, then record a macro containing your mapping, which jumps to the next match at the end: `qarXnq`. You can now manually apply the macro repeatedly via `@a`, or make it recursive via `qA@aq`, or `:let @a .= '@a'`. Execute this once `@a`, and it will run until it runs out of matches.

Comment: Ingo Karkat, I tried to let this work without success. P.e. take the imap <C-w> in insert mode as a test example. It will remove the last word in every search match found. How can I integrate this in your answer?

Comment: @remio: <C-w> is kind of stupid, you can remove the last word of a match with `%s/some other words \zsLAST//g`. But in general, use normal-mode commands and mappings with :normal. Your <C-w> can be done in normal mode via `bdw` (go to beginning of current word, then delete word).

Comment: Yes I know but its just an example. How do I use a <C-...> map on search matches?

Comment: I'm afraid you're going into a direction that is atypical Vim use. But, to answer: For normal mode <C-...> mappings, you have to quote the mapping this way: `execute "normal \<C-...>"`; if the mapping is an insert mode one, you first have to enter insert mode via `i`, e.g. `execute "normal i\<C-...>"`